# Android padding vs margins performance

Tags: android

I'm doing some property animation and wanted to know which is faster - to update margins or padding. Both are updated by extending `Property<T, V>`.

```
public static final Property<View, Integer> LINEAR_TOP_MARGIN_PROPERTY = new Property<View, Integer>(Integer.class, "") {
    @Override
    public Integer get(View view) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        return params.topMargin;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(View view, Integer value) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        params.topMargin = value;
        view.requestLayout();
    }
};

public static final Property<View, Integer> PADDING_BOTTOM_PROPERTY = new Property<View, Integer>(Integer.class, "") {
    @Override
    public Integer get(View view) {
        return view.getPaddingBottom();
    }

    @Override
    public void set(View object, Integer value) {
        object.setPadding(
                object.getPaddingLeft(),
                object.getPaddingTop(),
                object.getPaddingRight(),
                value
        );
    }
};
```

Padding looks to be more flexible, as it works in any layout without extensive `LayoutParams` casting and checking. Not all views have the same padding behavior, though.

Comment: They do different things. Use the property that makes the most sense for your layout. Both changes require a new layout pass; why would you think there is a performance difference at all?

Comment: if you are on API 14+, why do you use LayoutParams for View position settings?

Comment: @pskink instead of animating position? I need to stack a few views in `LinearLayout`, this is easier than calculating positions.

Comment: yse transitionX/transitionY properties